# Conditionally pick a prop to use

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements, react-props

```
const Component = ({

    const someBoolean 

    return (
          <Component
             prop1
             prop2
```

I want to use prop1 ONLY when someBoolean is true, otherwise prop2 should be used. What is the best way to do this ?

So say someBoolean is true I would have

```
const Component = ({

    const someBoolean 

    return (
          <Component
             prop1
```

Otherwise I would have

```
const Component = ({

    const someBoolean 

    return (
          <Component
             prop2
```

Comment: are prop1 and prop2 booleans? If so you can do `prop1={someCondition}`

Comment: No they are strings

Comment: _How_ you are defining `someBoolean` would give us a better idea of how to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to do this is with ternary operators. I'm new to React and this I believe is how you can implement conditional rendering

```
const Component = ({

    const someBoolean 

    return (someboolean ? <Component prop1> : <Component prop2>)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use spread operator.

```
const Component = ({
    const someBoolean;
    const finalProp = someBoolean ? prop1 : prop2;   

    return (
          <Component {...finalProp} />
    )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const Component = ({

    const prop = someBoolean ? prop1 : prop2 

    return (
          <Component {...prop} />
})
```

Comment: prop names are fixed so this cant be done

Comment: Then I would do what @tempnameenjoyer suggested above